# How to Ignore logging

Tags: java, annotations, slf4j

Currently, my code uses an implementation of slf4j. The logger is fetched using a url (wsdl). Due to this, I am unable to test my code in a stand alone dev env, unless I bring up the giant server which hosts the service. Other than commenting the relevant code, does anyone know of a way I could make my eclipse ignore the usage of org.slf4j,impl.LoggingService in a class? I think an annotation like @Ignore which takes class params would have been fantastic. This could help someone pass those classes as params which being called in code need to be ignored.  I am open to writing my own annotation implementations for it. Thank you

Comment: you could mock the call to the server you know

Comment: yeah, lets just say I cannot in my current scenario (primarily, for reasons, since I dont have soapui and the url is generic for multi- tenants that are created at runtime and other things.. etc .. )

Answer (score 3):

SLF4J seperates out the logging API from the underlying implementation, you should be able to switch out the implementation at runtime by selecting a different logging implementation. So for example slf4j-noop.jar that ignores all logging requests.

Comment: Indeed, it does. And currently I am using an internal implementation of slf4j. My only requirement right now is to ignore the logging code.